# from what I read, "grub>" is a linux-thing, so how come it appeared on my pc?

Tags: windows-7, grub, bootloader, bootable-media, debug

Ok, here's what I get when trying to boot into my Windows 7 Ultimate installation:

First, there's something about SLIC LOADER v 1.4.6, followed by a bunch of non informative information and a countdown cursor at the bottom of the screen, starting from 25...

When that reaches zero, I'm transfered to another page that says:

*drive 0x80(LBA): C/H/S=14594/255/63, Sector Count/Size=234452610/512

Partition num:0, active, filesystem type is ntfs, partition type 0x07

Partition num:1, filesystem type is ntfs, partition type 0x07

* * * *

Options if your HDD is larger than 1TB

* Move your boot files to a smaller partition at the start of the HDD

* Format the HDD and allow Windows to create a 100MB boot partition

* Shrink and move your partitions with GParted


Press any key to read more...

_*
Pressing any key takes me to the next page:
*Options if you have an OEM/Recovery partition:

* Format the whole HDD with Active@ Kill Disk

* If possible use EasyBCD to relocate the boot files


Tools to use:

* EasyBCD to move your boot files

* Active@ Kill Disk (ISO) to format

* GParted to resize, move & create partitions


How to boot back into Windows:

* Boot from your Windows DVD and select "Repair your computer"

* Select  Command Prompt

* Enter "bootsect/nt60 SYS/force" or "bootsect/nt60 ALL/force"

* Reboot


Press any key to enter command line...*
Next screen is:
*[ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename. ESC at any time exists.]


grub> _*
Finally, pressing ESC takes me to this:
*Windows 7/Vista/Server

Windows 7/Vista/Server (No SLIC)

Debug (Default)

Debug (Legacy)

Windows NT/2000/XP
Loader Help


Use the ↑ and ↓ keys to highlight an entry.

Press ENTER or 'b' to boot.

Press 'c' for a command-line.*
This occurred after updating to the latest version of my ESET antivirus software...
NOTE that I have never had any other OS apart from Windows 7 installed on my computer.
During the last week I have been running Ubuntu Studio from a live usb.
This is the only external storage device available: a 16GB Kingston USB stick
Only computer available apart from the faulty one is a MacBook Air.
I tried to turn the stick into a bootable Windows 7 USB via BootCamp Assistant and a few Terminal tweaks, but whenever I ran it, I kept getting an error about some corrupt Recycle Bin or something, so I went with the Ubuntu Studio live USB instead.
Now I'm afraid to do anything else with it, 'cause it's the only working OS I got at the moment.
So my two question are: What may have caused all this?
What should I do in order to resolve my predicament?
I'm starting to lean towards formatting my hard drive, but any other ideas would certainly be appreciated.
No installation CDs available.
System details
Motherboard: Gigabyte H55M-UD2H
CPU: Intel Core i7-860
RAM: 8GB
Storage Devices: two Kingston SSDs - one of 120GB (that I 've got Windows installed on, and that's running low on space), and one of 480GB (that I really hope I won't have to format).

Comment: How did you set up the Ubuntu Studio USB drive?

Comment: @8bittree [These](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-pc-on-a-mac--cms-21187) are the best instructions I have found...

Comment: So you made it with the Mac? I suppose that reduces the likelihood that you accidentally installed the bootloader to the Windows drive instead of the Ubuntu one while creating it.

Comment: @8bittree Yup. My Windows pc was already unbootable/unusable when I created the ubuntu usb. So it's elsewhere that things went wrong...